# Mac/Linux equivalent to resource monitor's disk activity with filenames?

Tags: linux, mac, filenames, resource-monitor, disk-activity

In Windows, the resource monitor allows you to see the filenames associated with the disk activity, but tools like iotop and activity only show overall disk activity from processes instead of the individual files being accessed. Is there such a tool?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`ftop`](https://code.google.com/p/ftop/)?

> Ftop is to files what top is to processes. The progress of all open files and file systems can be monitored.

Comment: Oh sorry, ftop shows the files but has an issue with refreshing. It seems to "jerk" around instead of refreshing you'd see with top.